# How to add/update utterances for Lex intents through Lambda Python?

Tags: aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

I am able to add utterances through console and also using the CLI, but I need to retrieve utterances from some database and feed it to the chatbot. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is way too broad, I don't even get the question. Do you want to create utterances from Python based on data you have in a DB?

Comment: basically I want to add/update the utterances, intents etc using Python (Lambda) @imTachu

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/imTachu/ShakiraChatbot/blob/master/setup.py), in this example I create the chatbot, all intents, utterances using boto3, I never upload this to lambda because I don't need to but if you really want to you can

Comment: thanks for the help @imTachu, but honestly I could not understand what was going on there.